# Cómo limpiar elementos de un dropdown al cerrar ventana modal

Tags: javascript, select2

Tengo una ventana modal es con código `HTML` y `CSS` puro (no `Bootstrap`),

Estoy usando la librería `select2` (versión 4) y tengo 2 `dropdown` que se cargan con un listado de la BD.

Lo que estoy intentando es limpiar los `dropdown` al presionar el botón **cerrar** de la ventana modal. He probado con todos los códigos para limpiar que recomiendan en los post y no tengo resultados.

Adjunto mi código `JS` y los códigos que he probado:

```
 <div class="select w50">
     <label for="">Lugares</label>
     <select name="lugares" id="lugares" class="nuevo" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="lugares" style="width: 95%; height:40px">
          <option value=""></option>
          {{lugares}}
      </select>
 </div>
 <div class="select w50">
    <label for="">Ruta</label>
    <select name="ruta" id="ruta" class="nuevo" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="ruta" style="width: 95%">
        <option value=""></option>
        {{lugares}}
     </select>
  </div>
  <div class="inputBox w100">
       <input type="button" class="btn-2" value="Generar">
       <input type="button" class="btn-2" value="Cerrar" id="cerrar">
  </div>
```

```
const cerrar = d.getElementById('cerrar');

function cerrarModal2(){
    document.querySelector("#memo-modal").style.display= 'none';
    document.getElementById("descripcion").value = "";
    document.getElementById("lugar").value = "";
    document.getElementById("invitacion").value = "";
    document.getElementById("fecha").value = "";
    tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent("");
}

cerrar.addEventListener("click", cerrarModal2);
```

codigos que he probado

```
$('#id').val('').trigger('change');
$("#id").select2('data', null);
$('#id').val([]).trigger('change');
let limpiar = new Option("", 0, false, false);
$('#id').append(limpiar).trigger('change');
$('#id').val(null).trigger('change');
```

Comment: Podrías agregar todo el código relevante? Qué es la variable `cerrar`? por ejemplo. te recomiendo que leas [example]

Comment: cerrar es el id que hace referencia al boton para cerrar la ventana modal

Comment: Agrega el HTML que tienes, así es más fácil entender tu problema

Comment: Prueba con `$("#id").val(null).trigger("change");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los métodos que estás probando son propios de `jQuery`, verifica que estés incluyendo la librería en tu proyecto y de ser así, prueba con `$('#lugares').html('')`. En caso contrario no te van a funcionar esos métodos.

También puedes probar con `JS` puro, con algo como esto

`document.getElementById('lugares').innerHTML = '';`.

Con eso eliminas todo el contenido interno del elemento `select` es decir, los `option`.

**Ejemplo con `jquery`:**

```js
$('#limpiarSelect').on('click', function(){
  $('#prueba').html('');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="prueba">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="1">uno</option>
  <option value="2">dos</option>
  <option value="3">tres</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<button id="limpiarSelect">Limpiar select</button>
```

**Ejemplo con `JS` puro:**

```js
function limpiarSelect(){
  document.getElementById('prueba').innerHTML = "";
};
```

```html
<select id="prueba">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="1">uno</option>
  <option value="2">dos</option>
  <option value="3">tres</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<button onclick="limpiarSelect();">Limpiar select</button>
```

Comment: gracias, lo he solucionado probe tu codigo y funciona con la diferencia que limpia por completo las opciones(eso queda para futuros usuarios), mi problema es que estaba apuntado con otro id de otra modal, este es el codigo que me funciona:  $('#lugares2').val('').trigger('change'); no encuentro la opcion para dar como respuesta tu codigo

Comment: Ahora entiendo. Es que en la pregunta dices _Lo que estoy intentando es **limpiar** los `dropdown` al presionar el botón cerrar de la ventana modal_. Con **limpiar** asumí que querías eliminar todo el contenido del `select`. Error mío de interpretación, una disculpa por ello. **Me alegra que hayas encontrado la solución**. Para aceptar la respuesta, hay un check al lado izquierdo de la misma, debajo de los botones para dar votos positivos o negativos. Aunque, lo dejo a tu consideración ya que mi respuesta no soluciona directamente el problema que tenías, pero puede servir de referencia futura.